# Assigning a role based on signup url on a Drupal 7 site?

Tags: users

I need to give out a URL that will grant people who sign up at that URL a specific role. If possible I would like to also have the user fill out profile fields as part of user registration.

I think the Profile 2 module does something like this, but this is already set up with normal Drupal fields, is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with [Auto Assign Role](https://drupal.org/project/autoassignrole) module, It provide paths that will trigger a specific role when an account is created.

> The Auto Assign Role serves three primary purposes. The first is to
>   provide an automatic assignment of roles when a new account is
>   created. The second is to allow the end user the option of choosing
>   their own role or roles when they create their account. The third is
>   to provide paths that will trigger a specific role when an account is
>   created. The administrator has full control over these functions and
>   can have them working together or independently of each other. Auto
>   Assign Role is integrated with the Content Profile module so that you
>   can have content types serving as registration pages. You can even
>   replace the default user/register page with a customized version of
>   your own design.

Comment: I installed it and couldn't find the settings for assigning a role based on a path, so I assumed that was in the dev version so I installed that, and I still couldn't find the settings. I get the impression that assigning a role based on a path only works in the Drupal 6 version.

Comment: @jmickela yaa, they mentioned "We will wait for an official D7 release of Auto Assign Role module." in this project page https://drupal.org/project/autoassignroleblocks

Answer (score 2):

I know the auto assign roles will work but often you want different customer fields or required fields as well.  I have found that [Profile 2 registration path](https://drupal.org/project/profile2_regpath) will give custom fields per role and path registration.